# WPF: Image paths in ListBox, Display Image in place of path

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, c#-4.0

I have a ListBox filled with paths of different images.  How will I alter the ItemTemplate so that the images will be shown instead of paths(string).

Here is the code:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Path=Content}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0083A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0102A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0103A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0104A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0105A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0106A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ItemTemplate` of a `ListBox` is copied to the `ContentTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem` during UI generation. However, when adding the `ListBoxItem`s directly, `ItemTemplate` is ignored for items already of the `ItemsControl`s container type (`ListBoxItem` for `ListBox`, `ListViewItem` for `ListView` etc.). So in this case, you'll have to use the ContentTemplate of the `ItemContainerStyle` directly instead.

Also, change `Source="{Binding Content}"` to `Source="{Binding}"`

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0083A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0102A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0103A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0104A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0105A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C:\Users\AKSHAY\Pictures\IMG0106A.jpg</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. BTW from where do u people get to know such ins and outs of WPF. All books seems to be teaching the concepts superficially.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an IValueConverter that converts a string to a ImageSource.

Something like:

```
public class ImagePathConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value as string));
  }
  public object ConvertBack(xxx) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

And then create a value converter resource and use that in your binding.

a resource could be defined like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <myNameSpaceAlias:ImagePathConverter x:Key="ImagePathConverter"/>
...
```

and then bind with:

```
{Binding Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the XAML using this value converter?

Comment: I did this but still it did not work: <ListBox> <ListBox.Resources> <local:ImageConverter x:Key="MyConverter"></local:ImageConverter> </ListBox.Resources> <ListBox.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=MyConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"></Image> </DataTemplate> </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a value converter  in the binding and pass a bitmap image